Issues building AOSP for Pixel 6 with lunch command
The general direction are here, where it says the command should be in this format with:
lunch <product_name>-<release>-<build_variant>
... or following the directions ...
lunch aosp_oriole-trunk_staging-userdebug

Why:

According to the codenames listed here, the Pixel 6 is oriole
It says release is always trunk_staging
I chose the userdebug build variant

In totality, my setup looks like this:
repo init --partial-clone -b android-14.0.0_r73 -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync -c -j16 --fail-fast -v
tar xzvf google_devices-*.tgz
./extract-google_devices-*.sh
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_oriole-trunk_staging-userdebug

Why that branch and tar:

This indicates the newest branch for the Pixel 6 is android-14.0.0_r73, which is build id AP2A.240905.003.F1
This indicates the binaries file to use for build id AP2A.240905.003.F1

If I run lunch aosp_oriole-trunk_staging-userdebug
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:380:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:51:
build/make/core/release_config.mk:145: error: No release config found for TARGET_RELEASE: trunk_staging. Available releases are: ap2a.
17:11:37 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

If I run lunch aosp_oriole-ap2a-userdebug
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:380:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:51:
build/make/core/release_config.mk:227: error: fopen failed.
17:14:55 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

If I run just lunch, which should give me the menu of targets:
You're building on Linux

Warning: Cannot display lunch menu.

Note: You can invoke lunch with an explicit target:

  usage: lunch [target]

Which would you like? [aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-eng]
Pick from common choices above (e.g. 13) or specify your own (e.g. aosp_barbet-trunk_staging-eng):

Anyone have any suggestions?

https://xdaforums.com/t/lunch-failed.4665348/ this might help you.
